# Обнаружено потенциально опасное значение Request.Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Здравствуйте,передаю через скрытое поле переменную с js в asp.net
Переменная содержит html код,и мне выводится ошибка

Обнаружено потенциально опасное значение Request.Form, полученное от клиента (div_value=" Лого...").

*Описание: Процедура проверки запросов обнаружила потенциально опасное входное значение клиента; обработка запроса прервана. Это значение может указывать на попытку нарушить безопасность приложения, например, через атаки "cross-site scripting". Чтобы разрешить страницам переопределять параметры проверки запросов приложения, в разделе конфигурации httpRuntime для атрибута requestValidationMode задайте значение requestValidationMode="2.0". Пример: . После установки этого значения можно отключить проверку запросов путем установки значения validateRequest="false" в директиве Page или разделе конфигурации . Однако в этом случае настоятельно рекомендуется явно проверять в приложении все введенные данные. Дополнительные сведения см. в разделе http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153133. 
Сведения об исключении: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: Обнаружено потенциально опасное значение Request.Form, полученное от клиента (div_value=" Лого...").*

Подскажите как должен правильно выглядеть web.confg, что б ошибки не было
Так мой выглядит

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  [url]http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433[/url]
  -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
        <httpRuntime 
          requestValidationMode="2.0" 
          />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  [url]http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433[/url]
  -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"  />
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Но лучше отключать валидацию на конкретной странице:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[ValidateInput(false)]` - для метода.

`[HtmlAllow]` - для свойства модели.